# How to to set a background image on a navigation bar?

Tags: css, image, background, navigationbar

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with a background image, including `ul` and `li` as links, but could not succeed.

I don't have a path error, as I have other `img` elements that render properly. The html part is just `ul` and `li` elements inside the nav area.

css:

```
#main_menu {background-image:url(resources/images/navbar.png);height:40px;}
```

I have searched the web for solutions, but I haven't found any that works. I have tried position, size and repeat.

**Edit:** I have made the `ul` and `li` menu inline, so they fit the 40px height.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing bracket at the end of the image path, should be:

```
#main_menu {background-image:url(resources/images/navbar.png);height:40px;}
```

You also probably want to set the background-repeat and background-position properties in the background style...

**EDIT**
Are your list items floated? If they are, they need to be cleared or the container will collapse and that would cause the background image not to be displayed

Comment: I had included the closing bracket (typo), and I have messed around with repeat and background-image-size. Position didn't help either, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `height` from the rule which defines the background img.

So something like

```
#main_menu {background-image:url(resources/images/navbar.png); height:40px;}
```

Right now you have it lumped in with the file path, which is not closed because it is missing a bracket.